# Image upload error using Bottle

Tags: python, file-upload, bottle

In my code `.tpl`  file:

```
<form method='post' action='/upload' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
   <input type='file' name='newfile'>
   <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

My controller code is:

```
@app.post('/upload')
def upload():
  newfile = request.files.get('newfile')
  save_path = os.path.join(config.UPLOAD_DIRECTORY, newfile.filename)
  newfile.save(save_path)
  return redirect('/')
```

After browse and submit, I got following 500 error.

```
Internal Server Error
```

Exception: `AttributeError('save',)`

Traceback:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/var/www/myproject/bottle.py", line 768, in _handle
 return route.call(**args)
 File "/var/www/myproject/bottle.py", line 1518, in wrapper
 rv = callback(*a, **ka)
 File "/var/www/myproject/controllers/index.py", line 753, in upload
 newfile.save(save_path)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/cgi.py", line 521, in __getattr__
 raise AttributeError, name
 AttributeError: save
```

Could someone know what this issue is?

Comment: Can you specify which WSGI server you are using?  I have found problems with some when saving files. I have found cherrypy works the best with bottle, or gevent.pywsgi if you want async.

Comment: I am using cherrypy. But still, problem is same. 
UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = 'var/www/myproject/images/' and I set all permissions to that folder.

Comment: which version of Bottle are you using/

Answer (score 0):

Oh I see a problem...

```
return redirect('/')
```

Should be:

```
redirect('/')
```

That could what is generating your 500 issue.